# Using @HTML.EditorForModel & DisplayForModel with ViewModels in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Coming from a Silverlight background, MVVM is solidly planted in my mind.  Moving to MVC, although rewarding, has been something of a paradigm shift for me.

One of the questions I have is about using EditorForModel when the strongly typed view has been passed a ViewModel with the object to be editted as a property, rather than the POCO being directly passed in as the model, with no viewmodel encapsulated around it.

How can I use EditorForModel on a property of the model, rather than the whole model itself?  I went looking for something akin to @HtmlHelper.EditorForModel(model.Customer), but coulndt find an overload.  It seems you can only generate an editor for the whole model...

(where customer is a good 'ol poco)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try -

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
```

Comment: does that work where name is a complex type?  ie, Name is actually the poco, with multiple properties, I want the form to be set up as?  OK, I'll try it when I get home later.

Comment: Ya know, when I saw your response I thought "could it be that easy"?  Yup, it is.  Many many thanks for helping me see the obvious :-)
Could I ask a followup question please?  Can the default selection the editor makes for some of the properties be influenced?  I am especially interested in placing a dropdownlist for one of the properties, but am clueless for how best to do it.  Again, thank you very much

Comment: @Joe - Thanks for saying thanks, happy the answer helped.  With regards to setting up a drop-down for one of your properties, you could have a look at this series of blog posts - http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html